# Do squirrels fed by humans develop cancer and heart disease?

Tags: zoology

In Michael P Ghiglieri and  Thomas M. Myers's book [Over the Edge: Death in Grand Canyon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/097009731X) (a chronicle of deaths in the Grand Canyon by a biologist and a medical doctor), in the section about squirrels biting humans who are feeding them, it is mentioned in passing that,

> Due to their penchant for successfully duping then intimidating tourists, the chubby little guys actually become unhealthy.
>   Like many of the humans feeding them, the **squirrels too die younger from heart disease, cancer and other problems relating to obesity.**

(page 414)

However, there are no references to back it up.

Are there **any scientific studies showing a link between human food and squirrels getting cancer/heart disease?**

Comment: Perhaps it would be relevant to ask whether wild squirrels live long enough to develop cancer & heart disease, rather than becoming food for coyotes, hawks, and other predators?